# Is it true that Jayadratha had split personality disorder?

Tags: scripture, mahabharata

As per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duhsala) Jayadratha had a split personality disorder. It is mentioned that due to such disorder, he misbehaved with women during his life time.

For example: he tried to kidnap and molest Draupadi

Does any scripture supports this claim?

Comment: Wikipedia claims everything. There is a banner on the Wikipedia article which says that there are no citations to the article. We need not to discuss which is a fable. Take it as a grain of salt.

Comment: @Sinister i am taking it with grain of salt. that is the reason why i am asking it to "experts" in this community with supported scriptural reference, if any.